# Custom Testable instance with QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, testing, monads, quickcheck

I have a custom result/error monad, nothing fancy:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM, ap)

data MyResult a = Error String | Success a

instance Functor MyResult where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative MyResult where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad MyResult where
    (Error   s) >>= f = Error s
    (Success a) >>= f = f a
    return = Success
```

I want values in this monad to instantiate QuickCheck's `Testable` class, so I can write properties that hold (i.e. pass tests) when a value is `Success _`, and not hold (i.e. fail tests) when a value is `Error _`.

For example, I would like to be able to write a test like this:

```
myProp :: Property
myProp = forAll (arbitrary :: Int)
    (\x -> if x == 0 then Error "0 not allowed" else Success ())
```

and have the `String` in the `Error` be the test failure message if the test fails.

I assume I need to instantiate `Testable` for `MyResult`:

```
instance Testable t => Testable (MyResult t) where
    property (Success _) = undefined -- what goes here?
    property (Error   s) = undefined -- what goes here?
```

However I can't figure out how I should implement the `property` function in `Testable`, despite reading the [QuickCheck documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) and [relevant source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#Testable).

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a `Property` from your result. The easiest way to do this is

```
property (Success _) = property True
property (Error _)   = property False
```

You could also convert your `Error` result to a Quickcheck `Result`

```
property (Error s)   = property $ failed { reason = s }
```

See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html for the definition of `failed`

Comment: Is there something else I can put for `Error` that will pass the error message to QuickCheck?

Comment: Sure, you could also use the `Result` data type, .e.g. `property $ MkResult ...`

Comment: How exactly does one go about doing this? I recognise `MkResult` from the quickcheck source but I can't find any information on how to use it.

Comment: @AlexJ136 see my addendum